# how to avoid preventdefault

Tags: jquery, blogger, preventdefault

I am using a free blogger template and there is the possibility to submit a form with some information. Some are optional some are required. The piece of code that takes care of sending the email is

```
$('#send-order').click(function(e) { e.preventDefault(); passEmail() });
```

and passEmail is simply this

```
function passEmail() {
    simpleCart({
        checkout: {
            type: "SendForm",
            method: "POST",
            extra_data: {
                firstname: document.getElementById("first_name").value,
                lastname: document.getElementById("last_name").value,
                email: document.getElementById("email").value,
                phone: document.getElementById("phone").value,
                address: document.getElementById("address").value,
                postcode: document.getElementById("postcode").value,
                comments: document.getElementById("message").value
            }
        }
    });
    simpleCart.checkout();
};

function cleanUrl(url) {
    return url.replace(/^https?\:\/\//i, "")
};

function storeUrl() {
    return $(location).attr('hostname')
}
simpleCart.bind('beforeCheckout', function (data) {
    data.first_name = document.getElementById("first_name").value;
    data.last_name = document.getElementById("last_name").value;
    data.phone = document.getElementById("phone").value;
    data.email = document.getElementById("email").value;
    data.address = document.getElementById("address").value;
    data.postcode = document.getElementById("postcode").value;
    data.comments = document.getElementById("message").value;
});
```

There is a way to bypass the preventDefault() so that the email doesn't go through the validation process?

Comment: Where does the validation process occur?

Comment: @JackPattishall I think that the validation is made somehow on the computer of the person that provided the template. Whenever you try to send it without filling all the required fields you get the alert that says: "the page at www.xyz.com says:..." where xyz is the page of the guy that created the template. I guess there is no way to bypass it right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`e.preventDefault()` in this context looks like it's because `#send-order` is an `<a>` or more likely a submit button `<input type="submit"/>`. You can make `#send-order` a clickable `<div>`. I'm not sure that'll allow you to bypass validation though...

**UPDATE**

Sometimes, I find it easier to use a quick and dirty non-semantic `<div>` button:

```
<div id="send-order" style="cursor: pointer; pointer-events: auto;">SEND</div>
```

I'm pretty sure you can use `<button id="send-order">SEND</button>`there's no default behavior expected from it afaik.

Comment: I tried to change the button that has id="send-order" into a div but..nothing changed unfortunately.

Comment: @user2692552 I updated answer. Btw, when you assign that id to a new button, make sure you delete the other id. If you have 2 or more elements on the same page with the same id, your script will fail or you will get unexpected results.